# Search with um_activity (Ultimate member activity) post with post_meta and show all matching post_meta results

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using **Kleo-child theme**. I have an active plugin Ultimate member social activity. I want to search for any keyword from **um_shared_link post_meta** and see the result that keyword activity what I search for. What exactly should I do for that? Here is my code:

```php
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'update_my_custom_type', 99 );

function update_my_custom_type() {

    global $wp_post_types;

    if ( post_type_exists( 'um_activity' ) ) {

        // exclude from search results
        $wp_post_types['um_activity']->exclude_from_search = false;
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {

   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', 

get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_kleo_ajax_search', 'kleo_ajax_search' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_kleo_ajax_search', 'kleo_ajax_search' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'kleo_ajax_search' ) ) {

  function kleo_ajax_search() {

    //if "s" input is missing exit

    if ( empty( $_REQUEST['s'] ) && empty( $_REQUEST['bbp_search'] ) ) 
    {
      die();
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['bbp_search'] ) ) {

      $search_string = $_REQUEST['bbp_search'];

    } else {

      $search_string = $_REQUEST['s'];
    }

    $output   = '';
    $context  = 'any';
    $defaults = array(
      'numberposts'      => 4,
      'posts_per_page'   => 20,
      'post_type'        => 'any',
      'post_status'      =>  array('publish','inherit'),
      'post_password'    => '',
      'suppress_filters' => false,
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
           'key' => '_shared_link',
           'value' => $_REQUEST['s'],
           'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
     )
    );

    if ( empty( $defaults['post_type'] ) ) {
      $posts = null;
    } else {

      $defaults = apply_filters( 'kleo_ajax_query_args', $defaults );

      $the_query = new WP_Query( $defaults );
      $posts     = $the_query->get_posts();
    //  echo "the query is".$the_query->request;
      //die();
      /*$the_query_meta = new WP_Query($defaults_meta);
      $posts_meta = $the_query->get_posts();
      $posts = array_merge($posts,$posts_meta);*/
    }

    $members          = array();
    $members['total'] = 0;
    $groups           = array();
    $groups['total']  = 0;
    $forums           = false;


    if ( function_exists( 'bp_is_active' ) && ( $context == "any" || in_array( "members", $context ) ) ) {
      $members = bp_core_get_users( array(
        'search_terms'    => $search_string,
        'per_page'        => $defaults['numberposts'],
        'populate_extras' => false,
      ) );
    }

    if ( function_exists( 'bp_is_active' ) && bp_is_active( "groups" ) && ( $context == "any" || in_array( "groups", $context ) ) ) {
      $groups = groups_get_groups( array(
        'search_terms'    => $search_string,
        'per_page'        => $defaults['numberposts'],
        'populate_extras' => false,
      ) );
    }

    if ( class_exists( 'bbPress' ) && ( $context == "any" || in_array( "forum", $context ) ) ) {
      $forums = kleo_bbp_get_replies( $search_string );
    }


    //if there are no posts, groups nor members
    if ( empty( $posts ) && $members['total'] == 0 && $groups['total'] == 0 && ! $forums ) {
      $output = "<div class='kleo_ajax_entry ajax_not_found'>";
      $output .= "<div class='ajax_search_content'>";
      $output .= "<i class='icon icon-attention-circled'></i> ";
      $output .= __( "Sorry, we haven't found anything based on your criteria.", 'kleo_framework' );
      $output .= "<br>";
      $output .= __( "Please try searching by different terms.", 'kleo_framework' );
      $output .= "</div>";
      $output .= "</div>";
      echo $output;
      die();
    }

    //if there are members
    if ( $members['total'] != 0 ) {

      $output .= '<div class="kleo-ajax-part kleo-ajax-type-members">';
      $output .= '<h4><span>' . __( "Members", 'kleo_framework' ) . '</span></h4>';
      foreach ( (array) $members['users'] as $member ) {
        $image = '<img src="' . bp_core_fetch_avatar( array(
            'item_id' => $member->ID,
            'width'   => 25,
            'height'  => 25,
            'html'    => false
          ) ) . '" class="kleo-rounded" alt="">';
        if ( $update = bp_get_user_meta( $member->ID, 'bp_latest_update', true ) ) {
          $latest_activity = char_trim( trim( strip_tags( bp_create_excerpt( $update['content'], 50, "..." ) ) ) );
        } else {
          $latest_activity = '';
        }
        $output .= "<div class ='kleo_ajax_entry'>";
        $output .= "<div class='ajax_search_image'>$image</div>";
        $output .= "<div class='ajax_search_content'>";
        $output .= "<a href='" . bp_core_get_user_domain( $member->ID ) . "' class='search_title'>";
        $output .= $member->display_name;
        $output .= "</a>";
        $output .= "<span class='search_excerpt'>";
        $output .= $latest_activity;
        $output .= "</span>";
        $output .= "</div>";
        $output .= "</div>";
      }
      $output .= "<a class='ajax_view_all' href='" . esc_url( bp_get_members_directory_permalink() . "?s=" . $search_string ) . "'>" . __( 'View member results', 'kleo_framework' ) . "</a>";
      $output .= "</div>";
    }

    //if there are groups
    if ( $groups['total'] != 0 ) {

      $output .= '<div class="kleo-ajax-part kleo-ajax-type-groups">';
      $output .= '<h4><span>' . __( "Groups", 'kleo_framework' ) . '</span></h4>';
      foreach ( (array) $groups['groups'] as $group ) {
        $image = '<img src="' . bp_core_fetch_avatar( array(
            'item_id' => $group->id,
            'object'  => 'group',
            'width'   => 25,
            'height'  => 25,
            'html'    => false
          ) ) . '" class="kleo-rounded" alt="">';
        $output .= "<div class ='kleo_ajax_entry'>";
        $output .= "<div class='ajax_search_image'>$image</div>";
        $output .= "<div class='ajax_search_content'>";
        $output .= "<a href='" . bp_get_group_permalink( $group ) . "' class='search_title'>";
        $output .= $group->name;
        $output .= "</a>";
        $output .= "</div>";
        $output .= "</div>";
      }
      $output .= "<a class='ajax_view_all' href='" . esc_url( bp_get_groups_directory_permalink() . "?s=" . $search_string ) . "'>" . __( 'View group results', 'kleo_framework' ) . "</a>";
      $output .= "</div>";
    }

    //if there are posts
    if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
      $post_type_str = array();
      $post_types    = array();
      $post_type_obj = array();
      foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $post_types[ $post->post_type ][] = $post;
        if ( empty( $post_type_obj[ $post->post_type ] ) ) {
          $post_type_obj[ $post->post_type ] = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
        }
      }

      foreach ( $post_types as $ptype => $post_type ) {
        $output .= '<div class="kleo-ajax-part kleo-ajax-type-' . esc_attr( $post_type_obj[ $ptype ]->name ) . '">';
        if ( isset( $post_type_obj[ $ptype ]->labels->name ) ) {
          $output .= "<h4><span>" . $post_type_obj[ $ptype ]->labels->name . "</span></h4>";
        } else {
          $output .= "<hr>";
        }
        $count = 0;
        foreach ( $post_type as $post ) {

          $post_type_str[$post->post_type] = $post->post_type;
          $count ++;
          if ( $count > 4 ) {
            continue;
          }
          $format = get_post_format( $post->ID );
                    if( $post->post_type == 'attachment') {
                        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $post->ID );
                        $image = '<img src="'.aq_resize( $img_url, 44, 44, true, true, true ).'" class="kleo-rounded"/>';
                    } else {
                        if ($img_url = kleo_get_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID)) {
                            $image = aq_resize($img_url, 44, 44, true, true, true);
                            if (!$image) {
                                $image = $img_url;
                            }
                            $image = '<img src="' . $image . '" class="kleo-rounded">';
                        } else {
                            if ($format == 'video') {
                                $image = "<i class='icon icon-video'></i>";
                            } elseif ($format == 'image' || $format == 'gallery') {
                                $image = "<i class='icon icon-picture'></i>";
                            } else {
                                $image = "<i class='icon icon-link'></i>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
          $excerpt = "";

          if ( ! empty( $post->post_content ) ) {
            $excerpt = $post->post_content;
            $excerpt = preg_replace( "/\[(.*?)(?:(\/))?\](?:(.+?)\[\/\2\])?/s", '', $excerpt );
            $excerpt = wp_strip_all_tags($excerpt); //added to remove gogole adsense code from search excerpt
            $excerpt = char_trim( trim( strip_tags( $excerpt ) ), 40, "..." );
          }
          $link    = 'activity/?wall_post='.$post->ID;
          $result  = $post->ID;
          $classes = "format-" . $format;
          $output .= "<div class ='kleo_ajax_entry $classes'>";
          $output .= "<div class='ajax_search_image'>$image</div>";
          $output .= "<div class='ajax_search_content'>";
          $output .= "<a href='$link' class='search_title'>$result";
          $output .= $excerpt;
          $output .= "</a>";
          $output .= "<span class='search_excerpt'>";
          $output .= $excerpt;
          $output .= "</span>";
          $output .= "</div>";
          $output .= "</div>";
        }
        $output .= '</div>';
      }

      if ( ! empty( $post_type_str ) ) {
        if ( count( $post_type_str ) > 1 ) {
          $search_str_posts = '&post_type[]=' . implode( ',', $post_type_str );
        } else {
          $search_str_posts = '&post_type=' . implode( ',', $post_type_str );
        }

      } else {
        $search_str_posts = '';
      }

      $output .= "<a class='ajax_view_all' href='" . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) . '?s=' . $search_string ) . $search_str_posts . "'>" . __( 'View all results', 'kleo_framework' ) . "</a>";
    }

    /* Forums topics search */
    if ( ! empty( $forums ) ) {
      $output .= '<div class="kleo-ajax-part kleo-ajax-type-forums">';
      $output .= '<h4><span>' . __( "Forums", 'kleo_framework' ) . '</span></h4>';

      $i = 0;
      foreach ( $forums as $fk => $forum ) {

        $i ++;
        if ( $i <= 4 ) {
          $image = "<i class='icon icon-chat-1'></i>";

          $output .= "<div class ='kleo_ajax_entry'>";
          $output .= "<div class='ajax_search_image'>$image</div>";
          $output .= "<div class='ajax_search_content'>";
          $output .= "<a href='" . $forum['url'] . "' class='search_title'>";
          $output .= $forum['name'];
          $output .= "</a>";
          //$output .= "<span class='search_excerpt'>";
          //$output .= $latest_activity;
          //$output .= "</span>";
          $output .= "</div>";
          $output .= "</div>";
        }
      }
      $output .= "<a class='ajax_view_all' href='" . esc_url( bbp_get_search_url() . "?bbp_search=" . $search_string ) . "'>" . __( 'View forum results', 'kleo_framework' ) . "</a>";
      $output .= "</div>";
    }


    echo $output;
    die();
  }
}

function searchfilter($query) {

    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type',array('um_activity'));
    }

return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```